# Matrix reading from file, multiplication with multithreading

Tags: java

I have a code that read two matrices from files, multiply it and then write the result to the file. I want to modify it, so it use multithreading for all this actions (reading, multiplicating, writing, etc.). How can I solve this problem? Here is what I have now.

```
file1.txt
4 3 4 6
-1 10 4 -1
4 7 2 -8

file2.txt
3 0 0
0 3 0
0 0 3
0 2 4



 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String file1 = "file1.txt";
        String file2 = "file2.txt";

        List<ArrayList<Integer>> matrix1 = readFile(file1);
        List<ArrayList<Integer>> matrix2 = readFile(file2);

        int[][] result = multiplyMatrix(matrix1, matrix2);

        writetoFile(result);


    }

    public static int[][] multiplyMatrix(List<ArrayList<Integer>> matrix1, List<ArrayList<Integer>> matrix2) {
//I have implementation
        return result;
    }


    public static void writetoFile(int[][] matrix) {
       //I have implementation
    }

    public static List<ArrayList<Integer>> readFile(String filename) throws IOException {
      //I have implementation
        return a;
    }
```

Comment: is it a homework?

Comment: @Joe No, I have the implemetation without multithreading, but now I want to use it

Answer (score 0):

If you want improove the performance then multithreading reading and writing can't help. Because only one thread should write to file for preventing spoilage of content. A possible solution for multithread read is reading one line by one thread, but before reading we don't know the total line count. Multithread computation may be done like this

```
public List<List<Integer>> multiply(List<List<Integer>> matrix1, List<List<Integer>> matrix2) {
    List<List<Integer>> result;
    List<List<Integer>> matrix2T = matrix2.transpose();
    Collection<CompletableFuture> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0, n = matrix1.size(); i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0, m = matrix2.size(); j < m; j++) {
            futures.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> multiply(matrix1, matrix2T, result, i, j)));
        }
    }
    CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What is transpose() there?

Comment: Matrix transpose (just in meaning from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose))